# How to show post like facebook with multiple images in android app?

Tags: android

[image]

Similar to above `image` in post and images are less it should automatically adjust views like first image larger and other images smaller.On the last view, it should be +2 more.

Comment: You can use [Staggered Grid Layout Manager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html) to achieve this

Comment: @N.Moudgil Will try it thanks for help.